# jsPDF plugin not working upto ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jspdf

I'm using the jsPDF plugin to convert a html page into a pdf file. It's working fine in all the browsers *except* some versions of IE.

Up to IE 10, it's not working and in IE11 it's working. Is it possible to make it compatible with IE9 and IE10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsPDF is a html5 solution, their page stats that there is a lazy flash shim for ie9 and below but "Current build does not have IE6-9 shim enabled" so you will just need to get a version that does have it enabled

Comment: so. even if we use flash shim, we can get the result only in IE10 and >10... correct..?

Comment: You will just need to use an older version of jsPDF. Their website says: "jsPDF will work in IE6+*, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari 3+, Opera. For IE9 and below, we lazily load a Flash shim called Downloadify which enables the files to be downloaded. (Current build does not have IE6-9 shim enabled)" if you cannot find any older versions for download, the project is available on github - https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases - but you would need to dig through there to find the version you want yourself, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Internet Explorer 11.
You have to use the latest stable release https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases/tag/v1.0.272

All the examples of PDF generation supplied in the ZIP worked with IE 11.